# Missing random UITableViewCell after tableView.deleteRows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app that displays music records in a table. The table is divided in a section for each day.

The code works as intended, but as soon as an item gets deleted, some rows are rendered white. However, those white rows still can be deleted, but don't respond to the `didSelectRowAt`.

### Video showing the behavior

[image: After an item gets deleted, some rows are rendered white]

### View Hierarchy Debugger

[image: Tried to debug it in the view hierarchy debugger]

## My attempt

I've created a `UITableViewController` subclass and implemented the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` & `UITableViewDelegate`.

`appData` is a structure, which conforms the `Codable` protocol and is encoded & decoded as the app cycles through it's states.

`appData.scannedAlbums` is a dictionary of `String: [ScannedAlbum]` (i.e. "2018-02-21": [ album1, album2, album3 ... ])

Before I refactored the code to use sections, the view controller no problems to render the cell, even after an item was deleted.

### HistoryTableViewController

```
class HistoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    ...
```

### UITableViewDataSource

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums else { return 0 }

    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let albumsInSection = appDelegate.appData?.getAlbums(in: section) else { return 0 }

    return albumsInSection.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlbumCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell

    if let album = appDelegate.appData?.getAlbum(for: indexPath) {
        print("cellForRowAt \(indexPath): \(album.discogsResult?.title ?? album.barCode), \(cell.frame)")
        cell.update(with: album)
    }

    return cell
}
```

### UITableViewDelegate

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        guard let dateString = appDelegate.appData?.getDateString(for: indexPath.section) else {return}
        guard let albumsInSection = appDelegate.appData?.getAlbums(in: indexPath.section) else {return}
        guard let index = albumsInSection.index(of: albumsInSection[indexPath.row]) else {return}

        if albumsInSection.count == 1 {
            appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums.removeValue(forKey: dateString)
            tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
        }
        else {
            appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums[dateString]?.remove(at: index)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

### Update #1

Ruling out the if let

[image: Ruling out the if let]

### Update #2

No cell in view hierarchy

[image: View hierarchy]

Comment: Note this will have terrible performance because you are generating your data source again and again on every access.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah, maybe I have to refactor the appData structure to be a dictionary in first place. I'm still new to iOS development and this is my first app that deserves to be called "app".

Comment: ScannedAlbum is a class or struct , if struct can you try it a class ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan It's a struct. Just tried a class, but same bug appears

Comment: This may comes from the fact that you **if let** inside **cellForRowAt** can you force-unwrap and try , also what about changing the computed property logic to a function call that updates the dataSource instead of miss-synchronization of computed vars

Comment: I cannot see any error. Somehow I feel it could be connected with cell layout.

Comment: @Sh_Khan The cell would still be returned, but without any updates. However, I've added a `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` outside the condition, but the cell is not colored red. Will add a gif asap

Comment: you remove from **appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums.remove(at: index)** and checks with **if albumsInSection?.count == 1** can you here deal with one set either appdelegate or computed property and try ??

Comment: There are too many unknowns. For example, `scannedAlbums.index(of:` depends on correct implementation of Equality which we don't know anything about. I would start by printing `albumsByDate` before and after the deletion and check whether the correct item has been removed. It seems to me that `cell.update(with: album)` is not called.

Comment: @Sulthan It conforms the `Equatable` by implementing the `==`. It's just comparing a `Date` and a `String`

Comment: I see a lot of strange things in your code (for example `let album = albumsInSection?[indexPath.row]` you are converting `albumsInSection` to an optional just after you have unwrapped it!) but I see nothing that could cause that issue.

Comment: I've refactored the code, but still facing the same error... :/

Answer (score 0):

I found something that kinda works, but I have no idea **why** I have to write it like this..

After rewriting the code to have a dictionary as `appData.scannedAlbums` and moving all helper methods to appData itself, the table view still suffered from this visual bug after deleting.

However, after adding the update of my dictionary to the DispatchQueue.main.async queue fixed it, except that the delete animation seems to be odd.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if albumsInSection.count == 1 {
        self.appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums.removeValue(forKey: dateString)
        tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
    }
    else {
        self.appDelegate.appData?.scannedAlbums[dateString]?.remove(at: index)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

So this must be an issue with multi threading I guess? Since UI updates are on the main thread, but updating my `scannedAlbums` dictionary was not?

Would love to get some insights here as I want to fix this correctly.. :/

Comment: Could you possibly try to use a different cell? For example just a default `UITableViewCell`, seting only a label on it?

Comment: @Sulthan I've added the `Basic` cell as another prototype, gave it the identifier `BasicCell`and updated `dequeueReusableCell` to use that prototype – No more white cells.. So there must something wrong with my cell! Thanks for the hint, I'll investigate further!

Comment: That's what I tried to tell you yesterday :) Make sure that you are not retaining your cells somewhere, e.g. in a closure. That could cause some hard to find issue because then the cell is impossible to be reused.

Comment: @Sulthan It's the same code, using the same if-lets, with just a different cell though..I have a strong feeling this an auto layout issue I'm running into. However, my console logs are quiet

Comment: I have a strong feeling something wrong is happening inside your cell and it's not layout. For example, removing `contentView` from the cell would probably cause something similar.